# JSON request to ASP.NET API

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following JSON Data:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 0,
        "type": "camera",
        "option": [
            {
                "optionId": 1,
                "optionValue": "",
                "answered": "false",
                "lastanswerd": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "checkCategory",
        "option": [
            {
                "optionId": 1,
                "optionValue": "",
                "answered": "false",
                "lastanswerd": "false"
            },
            {
                "optionId": 2,
                "optionValue": "",
                "answered": "false",
                "lastanswerd": "false"
            }           
        ]
    }
}
```

How to pass JSON data into ASP.NET API request with which type of parameter in controller action?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your json to:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "type": "camera",
    "option": [
      {
        "optionId": 1,
        "optionValue": "",
        "answered": "false",
        "lastanswerd": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "checkCategory",
    "option": [
      {
        "optionId": 1,
        "optionValue": "",
        "answered": "false",
        "lastanswerd": "false"
      },
      {
        "optionId": 2,
        "optionValue": "",
        "answered": "false",
        "lastanswerd": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) gives us:

```
public class Option
{
    public int optionId { get; set; }
    public string optionValue { get; set; }
    public string answered { get; set; }
    public string lastanswerd { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Option> option { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net MVC automap and try to cast each key:value of json.

```
{"key1":"value", "key2":"value"}
```

You can access those values using params inside your function

```
public ActionResult Index(string key,string key2)
```

Or creating a class with public setter equal to your keys and a parameterless constructor.

```
public Class MyJson
{
    public string key1 {get;set;}
    public string key2 {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Index(MyJson model)
```

In your specific case your passing a List of Object so you should use

```
public ActionResult Index(List<MyJson> model)
```